# In which story does a child survive Hiroshima by diving in a pond?

Tags: identification-request

I am trying to identify a story about a boy who survived the attack on Hiroshima. My clearest memory is the moment of impact: the boy happens to be outside the city and dives into a pond just before the bomb hits, and so survives the immediate effects of the blast. (1)

After that my memory is hazy:

- I'm pretty sure he eventually gets sick and dies
- I thought he folded a hundred cranes in order to make a wish, but that was a real *hibakusha* child, [Sadako Sasaki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadako_Sasaki), who attempted to fold [one thousand](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_thousand_origami_cranes) before she died.

  - Perhaps he befriends the historical figure, and she is the one who dies?
  - <strike>Perhaps I have misremembered the main character, and she is the one who dives into the pool?</strike> (No, she was too young.)

(1)  [Apparently plausible.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/109888) Thanks Mithrandir for the link.

Comment: Folding a thousand origami cranes is a fairly widespread tradition; it's quite plausible that this fictional boy did so as well as the real child you found.

Comment: Also, can you really survive a nuclear blast by diving into a pond? That sounds even less plausible than sheltering inside a fridge.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - [yes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109888/123076).

Comment: @Randal'Thor thanks, updated the question with these tidbits

Comment: A similar story is the semi-autobiographical manga "Barefoot Gen" by Keiji Nakazawa. If I recall correctly, the author, a schoolboy at the time, bent down to pick something off the sidewalk at the time the bomb went off and was shielded by a low wall; the adult next to him (a teacher?) was killed.